# JAXB parsing error : ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: xml, jakarta-ee, jaxb, indexoutofboundsexception

I face a problem and i don't have any clue left to solve it !

The problem is quite simple, i generated JAXB classes from an XSD file. (A real complex one). But when the marshalling occurs I get an Array index out of range : [insert random negative number here]

```
    javax.ejb.EJBException: The bean encountered a non-application exception; nested exception is: 
    java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Array index out of range: -11
    at org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.BaseEjbProxyHandler.convertException(BaseEjbProxyHandler.java:358)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.BaseEjbProxyHandler.invoke(BaseEjbProxyHandler.java:286)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy60.parseXMLFromData(Unknown Source)
    at com.michelin.v2k.services.bo.integration.impl.CasingBufferServiceTestCase.generateDOOMessage(CasingBufferServiceTestCase.java:106)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:76)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:607)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at com.michelin.v2k.V2KAbstractTestCase$1$1.evaluate(V2KAbstractTestCase.java:236)
    at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:18)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:30)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Array index out of range: -11
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.util.CollisionCheckStack.findDuplicate(CollisionCheckStack.java:112)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.util.CollisionCheckStack.push(CollisionCheckStack.java:53)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.pushObject(XMLSerializer.java:471)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsXsiType(XMLSerializer.java:574)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.SingleElementNodeProperty.serializeBody(SingleElementNodeProperty.java:113)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeBody(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:286)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeBody(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:283)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsXsiType(XMLSerializer.java:619)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.SingleElementNodeProperty.serializeBody(SingleElementNodeProperty.java:113)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ElementBeanInfoImpl$1.serializeBody(ElementBeanInfoImpl.java:98)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ElementBeanInfoImpl$1.serializeBody(ElementBeanInfoImpl.java:127)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ElementBeanInfoImpl.serializeBody(ElementBeanInfoImpl.java:244)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ElementBeanInfoImpl.serializeRoot(ElementBeanInfoImpl.java:251)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ElementBeanInfoImpl.serializeRoot(ElementBeanInfoImpl.java:33)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsRoot(XMLSerializer.java:461)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.write(MarshallerImpl.java:292)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.marshal(MarshallerImpl.java:221)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractMarshallerImpl.marshal(AbstractMarshallerImpl.java:95)
    at com.michelin.v2k.services.bo.integration.impl.CasingBufferService.parseXMLFromData(CasingBufferService.java:450)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:76)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:607)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext$Invocation.invoke(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:158)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext.proceed(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:141)
    at com.michelin.xnet.ejb.config.GuiceInterceptor.intercept(GuiceInterceptor.java:77)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:76)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:607)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext$Invocation.invoke(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:158)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext.proceed(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:141)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.InterceptorStack.invoke(InterceptorStack.java:122)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.stateless.StatelessContainer._invoke(StatelessContainer.java:221)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.stateless.StatelessContainer.invoke(StatelessContainer.java:174)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.EjbObjectProxyHandler.businessMethod(EjbObjectProxyHandler.java:217)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.EjbObjectProxyHandler._invoke(EjbObjectProxyHandler.java:77)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.BaseEjbProxyHandler.invoke(BaseEjbProxyHandler.java:281)
    ... 30 more
```

I've seen quite a few topics about this error, saying this error occurs because the marshalling isn't a Thread-safe operation, so I tried solving this issue using ThreadLocals and I didn't worked. I also tried to set all the getters and setters to "synchronized" but it doesn't seems to work either.

So I was wondering if any of you guys ever faced this issue, and if you remember how you solved it. I'm currently clueless any intel would be a step forward in the right direction.

Thanks,
Kyariban

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not thread-safe marshaller/umarshaller means that You do not need to use ThreadLocal or Synchronized anywhere.

All you need is to create new marshaller/unmarshller out of JAXB Context every time when you need to marshal/unmarshal something.

You cannot keep reference to marshaller/unmarshaller anywhere outside the method where marshalling/unmarshalling happens. But you can (and must) have JAXBContext somewhere outside.
 Even ThreadLocal does not help, because thread can be reused out of some Thread Pool.

Also keep in mind - Create JAXBContext is very expensive operation and JAXBContext is thread safe.
Create marshaller/unmarshaller is very light operation and costs almost nothing comparing to JAXBConetxt

Comment: Thanks for the answer i'll try to do just that ! I'll keep you updated :)